# as many vs so many

Tags: word-usage

Could you please explain which variant "as many" or "so many" fits the sentence better:
"As a rule, you need 11 people in a team to play football. In our case we don't have **as/so** many people, as we only have 3-5 people per team."

As for me, both variants are correct without any change of the meaning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, given your context where a *requisite* number (11) is specified, most idiomatic would be **that many**:

> Eleven people are needed for the team. But we don't have *that* many people, so we have only 3-5 people per team.

where **that many** refers back to "eleven".

**as many** is used when comparing rough counts:

> She doesn't have as many social media contacts as her younger sister.

**so many**  is used with "gestalt" comparisons:

> The beach is really crowded. There weren't so many people the first time we visited.

**this many** and **that many** can also be used in gestalt comparisons:

> The beach is really crowded. There weren't this many people the first time we visited.
>
> The beach was really crowded. There weren't that many people the first time we visited.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim! 
It's really helpful!